# Rendering HTML from database table to view blade issue

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am having a problem by rendering some html stuff from a database table. I have a function that is calling and returning some html content from databse table, when i use {{ }} double curly braces it shows the content on page but as a plain text not rendered as html. After i try to use {!! !!} it does not show anything on page. i don't understand why and what's the solution in this case. My blade page contains the .blade extension as well.

Please advice.

```
$string = "<h1>Its H1 Tag</h1>";

{{ $string }}
```

Comment: Why would you store the HTML code in the database in the first place?

Comment: You're missing a quote at the end of your string. Is that a typo when copying it here, or an issue with your string?

Comment: @php echo $string;  @ endphp works fine. And {{ $string }} doesn't work. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 17):

**Displaying Unescaped Data**

By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

> Hello, {!! $name !!}.

if above not work then use below but not a good practice-

**in your case** you can use **htmlentities($string)**, **html_entity_decode($string)** on your data and then use **{{ $string }}** to render html.

Answer (score 9):

> For Laravel Version 5.6.* or higher use single Curley Braces

```
$string = "<h1>Its H1 Tag</h1>;

{!! $string !!}
```

Comment: this works without any errors

Answer (score 5):

It can be displayed by the following code too if above code doesn't work.

```
@php
 echo $string;
@endphp
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in the [Laravel Documentation Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade?source=post_page---------------------------#:%7E:text=Displaying%20Unescaped%20Data,in%20the%20content.)

> **Displaying Unescaped Data**
>
> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
> PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want
> your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>
> `Hello, {!! $name !!}.`
>
> Note: Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users
> of your application. **Always use the double curly brace syntax to
> escape any HTML entities in the content.**

Cheers!